# A Tricky Quetiones on Creative Algorithm in Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, contest-math

an agent is works between n producer and m consumers. i'th producer, generate $s_i$ candy and j'th consumer, consumes $b_j$ candy, in this year. for each candy that sales, agent get 1 dollar payoff. for some problems, one strict rule was defined that a producer should be sales candy to any producer that the distance between them is not greater than 100 KM (kilometers). if we have list of all pairs of producer-consumer that the distance  between them is lower than 100 KM, which of the following algorithm is goof for finding maximum payoffs? (suppose $s_i$ and $b_j$ may be becomes very large).

```
1) Maximal Matching

2) Dynamic Programming

3) Maximum Flow 

4) 1 , 3
```

this is a last question on 2013-Final Exam on DS course.  any hint or idea?

Comment: Is a producer allowed to sell to more than one consumer?  If yes, the resulting graph (showing where commodities go) is probably not a matching (2 edges coming off one producer).

Comment: i think yes, producer can sell to one or more consumer with respect to distance lower 100 KM, Dear @TravisJ.

Comment: What does DS mean?

Comment: Is the problem supposed to ask for an algorithm that is good or goof?